# C++ TCP Socket | cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string to ‘const char*’ | ‘server’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm new to c++ and I need some help with this tcp socket.

**ERRORS**:

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘int inet_pton(int, const char*, void*)’
if(inet_pton(AF_INET, target, &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)  
                                               ^
error: ‘server’ was not declared in this scope
connect(sock, (const sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h> 

#include <ctime>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

//Network related includes:
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

using namespace std;

struct args {
   ...
};

void *hit(void *input) {

    ...

    //socket creation
    const char* packet = ("...").c_str();
    int sock = 0, valread; 
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) 
    { 
      printf("\n Socket creation error \n"); 
      return 0; 
    } 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(dport); 

    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form 
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, target, &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0) { // <-- Error on this line  
        printf("\nInvalid address / Address not supported \n"); 
        return 0; 
    } 

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) { 
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n"); 
        return 0; 
    } 

    do {
        connect(sock, (const sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)); // <-- Error on this line

        //send packet
        for(j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            //send packet
            send(sock, packet, strlen(packet), 0 ); 
        }
        close(sock);

    } while(time(0) < timer);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    ...

    pthread_t threads [t];

    //threads creation
    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        ...

        //start thread
        int rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, hit, (void*) Args);
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

        if (rc) {
            cout << "Error: unable to create thread," << rc << endl;
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    //pthread_exit(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for the first error you need apparently target.c_str(), although it is hard to see how and where is target declared. For the second it is hard to say because I don't see where is server defined. But apparently not in this function. Please make your question and code snippets more readable.

Comment: Looks like `server`, if it is defined at all, is defined in another scope and cannot be seen where it is being used. I recommend hacking this question down to one problem and producing a [mcve] to demonstrate that one problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first error, `inet_pton()` expects a `const char*` as input, but you are giving it a `std::string` instead, which is not implicitly convertible to `const char*`. You can simply call `target.c_str()` to get one, though:

```cpp
if(inet_pton(AF_INET, target.c_str(), &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)
```

For the second error, there is no `server` variable defined. You need to change that to `serv_addr` instead, and also `const sockaddr*` needs to be changed to `struct sockaddr*` (or the `struct` omitted entirely, since this is C++):

```cpp
connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
```

Or:

```cpp
connect(sock, (sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
```

Note that you are already making a similar call to `connect()` just above your `do..while` loop, and then calling it again inside your loop. You can't re-`connect()` a TCP socket that is already connected.  So you need to decide how many times you actually intend to call `connect()`.  Are you intending to make only 1 TCP connection?  If so, then `connect()` needs to be called before the loop.  Or, do you intend to make multiple TCP connections, 1 per loop iteration? If so, note that you cannot reuse a socket after calling `close()` on it, so you will need to call `socket()` inside of the loop as well, to make a new socket for each `connect()`.